# Is 'localhost' the only major way to have Interprocess communication?

Tags: javascript, localhost, ipc

I have some experience with python and starting to learn Javascript. I know that python has some modules to easily open and communicate with anoter processes/python scripts. Javascript seems to only be able to do this with http requests or using localhost.

So I was thinking, do the python modules and all other IPC implementations use localhost inside their code, even if it doesn't appear in the 'surface'.

Is this approach really fast and effective?

If it's not the only one, how do other IPC implementations work?

Comment: @Rojo I would be hesitant to say one is higher/lower level than the other, they are both high-level languages that are executed via an interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript uses (mostly) only TCP sockets.

Python can use TCP sockets & Unix sockets. You are probably thinking of Unix sockets -- Unix sockets do not use hosts, they work within the local filesystem hierarchy.

For this reason they can potentially offer better performance.

Comment: This brings me two more doubts: Is there way to use these Unix Sockets with Javascript? And, 'Unix' makes me wonder if they exist on windows...

Comment: Anyway, I will make my research now that I have the names. Thank you very much.

Comment: Traditionally with Javascript you can only use TCP sockets.

However I believe nodeJS can use Unix sockets.

Windows 10 supports Unix sockets, as of April 2018 update.